# SPRING HIBERNATE BEST WAY TO TRANSFER OBJECTS TO VIEWS

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, lazy-loading, dto

Currently i am using fetchtype.eager in spring mvc using hibernate to transfer objects to show or use in spring views and controllers.but one of my friend said it increases the load and instead of that use lazy.but with lazy objects are not avilable in jsps .and unable to load child objects like one to amny many to many e.t.c.Can somebody advise me the best way (standard spring mvc using service DAO implementation pattern) to do this.

Thanks in advance
sri

Comment: Use **DTO** objects to transfer data to View,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Session in View is solve your problem
The Java Persistence API (JPA) allows an object oriented model to be mapped to a relational database. JPA is a standard specification for Java based Object Relational Mapping frameworks – in order to use JPA an underlying implementation must be available; the most common choice being Hibernate.

Both JPA an Hibernate support lazy loading of data to restrict the number of queries fired off to the database. In general this means that data will be loaded on demand when methods are called, on a loaded object, that require more data to be loaded. In order for this to work, the object that the method is called on must have been loaded by JPA and be part of the current running transaction.

In a Spring application, calls to demarcate transactions are generally handled by the Spring interceptors.Transactions are normally started when a method call is made on a Spring managed object and committed once that method call ends. This means that if a JSP page requests data by calling a transactional method on a Spring managed bean, then it can only access the data in that bean that has already been loaded within that call. Any calls for data that might be loaded lazily will fail because the object is no longer attached to a JPA transaction after that method call has returned.

Hibernate developers solved this problem using the Open Session in View design, which associates the active session (and hence it’s transaction) with the thread that makes the call. In this design, the transaction will be committed when the thread completed processing the request, rather than when a method call completes. This allows lazily loaded data to be loaded within the JSP page not just within Spring managed objects.

for more info see this links

https://vladmihalcea.com/the-open-session-in-view-anti-pattern/
http://smartkey.co.uk/development/open-session-in-view-pattern-spring-jpa/